# Java casting error when retrieving private key from keystore

Tags: java, certificate, digital-signature, keystore

I am currently in the process of attempting to digitally sign a SOAP message and I'm following the guide from Oracle at the below link:

[Programming With the Java XML Digital Signature API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/dig-signature-api-140772.html)

When I initially ran my code I got the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: trusted certificate entries are not password-protected
```

I then amended the following line from:

```
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =
(KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry
    ("mykey", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("changeit".toCharArray()));
```

to:

```
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("mykey", null);
```

However, I am now getting the following error message:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.security.KeyStore$TrustedCertificateEntry cannot be cast to java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry
```

Im going to assume the code explained at the above guide is correct therefore Im thinking there could be something wrong with my keystore certificates?

I did the following when importing my certificates into the keystore:

1) Created .pem from .pfx file using the following command:

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in myfile.pfx -out myfile.pem -clcerts
```

2) I then converted the .pem to a .der file due to the .pem format not importing into the keystore. I used the following command to convert from .pem to .der:

```
 openssl x509 -outform der -in myfile.pem -out myfile.der
```

3) Lastly, I imported my .der file by running the following command:

```
keytool -import -alias mykey -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file myfile.der
```

Any help with this issue would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually `keytool` can import a PEM _certificate_ just fine; your problem was that the output of `pkcs12 (import)` contains both privatekey and certificate(s) (usually more than one). `openssl x509` has the side-effect of copying _only one certificate_ out of the combined input to the new file, regardless of what `-outform` you use. But as answered, using only the certificate is wrong; signing requires the privatekey _and_ cert(s).

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085 that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to import the **private key** of the certificate into the keystore, and not only the public key. It is not recommended to update the standard cacerts of JVM. Use a new file

But your three steps are not really needed. Just use directly the pfx file as `PKCS12`  keystore instead of `JKS`

Comment: Thanks for the information @pedrofb - because of this I was able to fix the issue - the steps I used to fix it are shown below

Answer (score 0):

Per the above feedback from @pedrofb, I directly converted the .pfx file to a jks file using the following command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore "myfile.pfx" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore "newkeystore.jks" -deststoretype JKS
```

I then ran the following command to obtain the alias from the new keystore which I added to the code allowing me digitally sign my XML:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "newkeystore.jks" | findstr "Alias Creation"
```